# CSS: What will be an attribute's value if I specify it as "inherit", but no parent element defines it?

Tags: css, browser

Will it in particular always be **the browser's default**?

For example in this case:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="example.gif" style="border: inherit;">
  </body>
</html>
```

It seems to be the case based on my experiments, but a confirmation (esp. referring to CSS specs) would be great!

Many thanks!

Comment: The inherit keyword specifies that a property should inherit its value from its parent element.You have not defined any border css in parent so It's not make any difference on child

Comment: "*Inheritance propagates property values from parent elements to their children. **The inherited value of a property on an element is the computed value of the property on the element’s parent element. For the root element, which has no parent element, the inherited value is the initial value of the property.***", [see](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#inheriting).

Comment: here is a jsfiddle showing inherit: https://jsfiddle.net/ey41weyr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not defined the border-style in your parent element so it will inherit the default rule of the parent element when you use `inherit`. The default rule for the border-style is `none` so the img border will be set `border-style:none;`.

You can check the default value for border [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border).

**Every elements has its default/initial value.**